# Gretest lower bound and least upper bound of the sets.

Tags: real-analysis

What is the g.l.b and l.u.b of 
$$A=(7,8) , \ \ \ B=\{ \pi+1, \pi+1/2, \pi+1/3,\cdots\}?$$
Is it $7$ and $8$ respectively for $A$ and $\pi$ and $\pi+1$ for $B$? I just want to confirm whether I am right or not.

Kindly reply and please specify their maximum and minimum as well.

Comment: You have the right g.l.b. and l.u.b. The first has no max or min. The second has a max but no min.

Comment: You are welcome. I figure you do not need a formal answer since you know what's going on.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.